# Converting Python 2.7 code used to decompress a base64 encoded bitmap image to Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64, gzip, python-3.7

I have some code that worked in Python 2.7 but I am trying to learn Python 3 now and convert several legacy scripts.  I was using `base64.b64decode` to decode each line of a file containing bitmap images (one per line), then `StringIO.StringIO` and `gzip.GzipFile` to decompress as a string.

I may need to re-evaluate the entire process.  If there is a more efficient way to achieve this in Python 3 I am willing to learn it just point me in the right direction.

I have found where io has replaced `StringIO` but when I use `io.BytesIO` I get errors about the end of file markers. Alternately `io.StringIO` gives me errors about input types that aren't already `str` or `None`.

I have tried several different ways to convert the output of `io.BytesIO` back to string but rather than try to cover every error I have run into let's just say I'm stuck.

Legacy Python 2.7 code:

```
import base64
nowtext= "c:/input_path/"
nowhtml= "c:/output_path/"
with open (nowtext, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        zipped= base64.b64decode(line)
        import StringIO
        sio= StringIO.StringIO(zipped)
        import gzip
        u= gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=sio)
        unzipped= u.read()
        wrapper= """<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,%s" />"""
        h= open (nowhtml,'a')
        h.write(wrapper % unzipped + '\n')
```

Attempt at converting for Python 3

```
import base64
nowtext= "c:/input_path/"
nowhtml= "c:/output_path/"
with open (nowtext, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        zipped= base64.b64decode(line)
        import io
        sio= io.BytesIO(zipped)
        import gzip
        u= gzip.decompress(sio)
        unzipped= u.read()
        wrapper= """<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,%s" />"""
        h= open (nowhtml,'a')
        h.write(wrapper % unzipped + '\n')
```

Comment: Not strictly on topic but __please__ use some code fixer on this code, `import` inside `for` loop made me blind.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you added a line or two of sample input data and the expected output lines of HTML. I suggest you use *very small* images for those.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke sorry and thanks for the feedback, still learning.  The complete script is almost 1k lines so putting imports at the beginning or too far from when they are used is confusing to me when I need to change modules or update parts of code.  I'm not sure what best practice is but I read that if the module is already imported it skips importing again.

Comment: Not using 1k line and separate your code into smaller and meaningful chunks (modules) would be a good start. No harm done, I went only half-blind. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the data in a file object plus a `GzipFile()` object to decompress. Just decompress your data *directly*, with the [`gzip.decompress()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress). Your code mixed up `gzip.GZipFile()` and `gzip.decompress()`; don't pass a file object intended for one, to a function that works  directly on a `bytes` value.

I'm going to assume that the decoded data is itself a valid Base64 string (otherwise your Python 2 code could not have worked), so we need to decode the `bytes` value you get from decompression, with the ASCII codec:

```
import base64
import gzip

nowtext= "c:/input_path/"
nowhtml= "c:/output_path/"

with open(nowtext, 'r') as f, open(nowhtml, 'a') as output:
    for line in f:
        unzipped = gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(line)).decode('ascii')
        line = f'<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,{unzipped}" />\n'
        output.write(line)
```

Note that I open the output file just *once*. There is little point in slowing down your script by opening the file again and again for every separate line.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to python so this blew my mind a little bit.  It worked perfectly thanks so much.  It's going to take me a little bit to fully unpack this and how it will change my future approach.